# .remove() is not a function. Why nodejs is not recognicing my method?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am making with nodejs and mongoose an API for bootcamps and courses and the relation between is that a bootcamp might have many courses.

Now i am trying to delete on cascade so as i delete a bootcamp all the courses related should also be deleted.

In my model Bootcamp:

```
// Cascade delete courses when a bootcamp is deleted
BootcampSchema.pre('remove', async function(next) {
    console.log(`Courses being removed from bootcamp ${this._id}`);
    await this.model('Course').deleteMany({ bootcamp: this._id });
    next();
  });
  
  // Reverse populate with virtuals
  BootcampSchema.virtual('courses', {
    ref: 'Course',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'bootcamp',
    justOne: false
  });
```

bootcamps.js (controller):

```
// @desc    Delete a Bootcamp
// @route   DELETE /api/v1/bootcamps/:id
// @access  Private

exports.deleteBootcamp = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
        const bootcamp = await Bootcamp.findById(req.params.id);
        if(!bootcamp) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse(`Bootcamp not found with id of ${req.params.id}`, 404));
        }

        bootcamp.remove();

        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: {} });

})
```

So i send the request in postman and i get the following error: `bootcamp.remove is not a function`

Any idea why is this happening? Any other way to approach this?

Comment: Check to see what `Bootcamp.findById` returns. Whatever you're getting back, it does **not** have a `.remove` method.

Comment: It seems remove() is now deprecated. Any suggestions on how to delete on cascade? @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know if `remove()` is deprecated as you have mentioned in the comments, your code looks fine.

If you can really get `bootcamp` with `await Bootcamp.findById(req.params.id)` then the schema created for your class `Bootcamp` is built correctly.

Another alternative is to use `deleteOne()` instead.

```js
await Bootcamp.deleteOne({id: req.params.id}); // or {_id: req.params.id} depending on the id field name in your schema
```

you have also to update the middleware for this:

```js
BootcampSchema.pre('deleteOne', async function(next) { // replace 'remove' with 'deleteOne' 
    // your logic
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `remove` with `deleteOne` middleware

```
// Cascade delete courses when a bootcamp is deleted
BootcampSchema.pre('deleteOne', { document: true, query: false }, async function(next){
    console.log(`Courses being removed from bootcamp ${this._id}`);
    await this.model('Course').deleteMany({bootcamp: this._id});
    next();
});


exports.deleteBootcamp = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const bootcamp = await Bootcamp.findById(req.params.id);
  if (!bootcamp) {
    return next(
      new ErrorResponse(`Bootcamp not found with id of ${req.params.id}`, 404)
    );
  }
  await bootcamp.deleteOne();
  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: {} });
});
```